# I deleted Ubuntu partition and my laptop it was showing grub rescue screen

Tags: grub2, windows-8, grubrescue, rescue-mode

I deleted Ubuntu directly from drive by deleting partition option. On restarting my laptop it was showing GRUB rescue screen, which I didn't knew what to do. I went to bios and I changed some settings and now when I am restarting my laptop its loving bios straight away. Tell me what to do now.

Manufacturer : ASUS K55VM Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Start up your computer with the USB or DVD Windows 8 recovery media in the system.

When the computer boots off the recovery media, pick the Troubleshoot option.

Then choose Advanced Options.

and head on over to the Command Prompt.

The computer should reboot and then ask you for the account.

Click your account to continue.

Then login to get started.

We’re going to use the built in partitioning tool called diskpart to confirm that:

```
We have all the right partitions
EFI partition is formatted correctly.
```

In the black screen that looks like a dark abyss, type:

```
diskpart
```

and enter this command:

```
sel disk 0
```

Now that the first disk is selected we need to view all the partitions

```
list vol
```

Verify that the EFI partition is using the FAT32 file system then select the volume and assign a drive letter to it.

Let’s say your EFI partition is on Volume 3, the next thing you would type is:

```
sel vol 3
```

Then assign an arbitrary drive letter to the parition.  Let’s use v.

```
assign letter=v:
```

You should see a message saying: DiskPart successfully assigned the drive letter or mount point.

Exit the diskpart tool by typing:

```
exit
```

You should still be in the command prompt but outside of the DISKPART> prompt.

We need to repair the boot record.  We can pull that off like so:

```
cd /d v:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\

bootrec /fixboot
```

The CD command tells the command line interpreter to change the directory to the volume label that has the EFI boot record.

Then the bootrec /fixboot command attempts to repair the selected volume.

Now we need to recreate the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store, so let’s backup the existing store first

Type:

```
ren BCD BCD.old
```

Now that we backed it up, let’s recreate the BCD store:

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s v: /f ALL
```

Now remove the recovery media and reboot and you should be all set.

Source: windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-recovery-overview

Comment: I don't have Windows Recovery DVD or Usb.  But I do have Ubuntu bootable usb disk.

Comment: As an immediate solution, I would suggest to reinstall Ubuntu and then recover from Windows the boot record, and then remove Ubuntu recently. And do not forget to create DVD Windows 8 recovery media.